# C# WPF MVVM TreeViewItem ToggleButton NEVER shows up

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeviewitem

I have recently been working with `TreeView` to represent files on an SFTP server. The way things load, it gets directories first and adds those to the `TreeView`. Afterwards, it loops through the directories and and then populates the files.

The Model is as follows.

```
public class FileData : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _Display = "";
    public string Display
    {
        get
        {
            return _Display;
        }
        set
        {
            _Display = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Display"));
        }
    }
}

public class AlbumData : ViewModelBase
{
    public AlbumData(string albumName, List<FileData> albumFileList)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(albumName) || albumFileList == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        AlbumName = albumName;
        AlbumFiles = albumFileList;
    }

    public string AlbumName { get; set; } = "";

    private List<FileData> _AlbumFiles = new List<FileData>();
    public List<FileData> AlbumFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return _AlbumFiles;
        }
        set
        {
            _AlbumFiles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AlbumFiles"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
            <TreeView x:Name="ftpFilesTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerAlbums}">

                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding AlbumFiles}" DataType="{x:Type local:AlbumData}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumName}"/>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileData}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Then I have my `ObservableCollection` with the data for the `TreeView`.

```
    private ObservableCollection<AlbumData> _ServerAlbums = new ObservableCollection<AlbumData>();
    public ObservableCollection<AlbumData> ServerAlbums
    {
        get { return _ServerAlbums; }
        set
        {
            _ServerAlbums = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ServerAlbums"));
        }
    }
```

So, my big issue here is the `ToggleButton` is not showing up after items are getting added to the `TreeView`.

I have tried using Blend to create a custom `TreeViewItem` and tinkering with the `HasItems` property. I think the issue is `HasItems` is not getting updated as objects are getting added to to my `ServerAlbums[X].AlbumFiles` collection.

I was thinking I could do a gross hack and just manually set `HasItems` when stuff is added, but I feel there needs to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: `List<FileData> AlbumFiles` - make it `ObservableCollection<FileData>`. then it will get updated *in UI* after objects are added to ServerAlbums[X].AlbumFiles collection

Comment: @ASh OMG. OMG. I feel so dumb. Wow....how did I miss that?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment from @ASh, I was able to see that I was using a `List` instead of the correct `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class AlbumData : ViewModelBase
{
    public AlbumData(string albumName, ObservableCollection<FileData> albumFileList)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(albumName) || albumFileList == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        AlbumName = albumName;
        AlbumFiles = albumFileList;
    }

    public string AlbumName { get; set; } = "";

    private ObservableCollection<FileData> _AlbumFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileData>();
    public ObservableCollection<FileData> AlbumFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return _AlbumFiles;
        }
        set
        {
            _AlbumFiles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AlbumFiles"));
        }
    }
}
```